# Migrating .NET Framework 4.6.2 to .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

We have a set of class libraries which are created under.NET Framework 4.6.2, we want to move these libraries into .NET Core 2.0 or .NET Standard 2.0

We have the following ways,

- Create a new project and copy over the code.
- Convert your existing project by editing the CSPROJ  file.

Which one is better to migrate the libraries and will .NET Standard impact on performance over the the .NET core.

Is there any alternatives to migrate these collections.

Comment: Hi. Since both ways that you describe will allow you to do what you're asking about, I'm voting to close this as primarily based on opinion. You can do either, they both have their pros and cons but in the end you should be able to accomplish your taks with both approaches.

Answer (score 8):

I think there might be a misunderstanding of what .NET Standard 2.0 actually is.

**.NET Standard** was created to create a **common API surface** across multiple different **implementations** of .NET.

Those implementations include .NET Framework, Mono, **.NET Core** and more. In that sense - .NET Core is a version of .NET,  there is no connection between .NET Standard and .NET Core.

If you create a .NET Standard library it is basically **platform agnostic**, meaning it can run on any **implementation of .NET** that supports the version of .NET Standard you are targeting. This means if you upgrade an existing .NET Framework 4.6.2 library to .NET Standard, you are only getting portability of the library, but if you still use the library in an app targeting .NET Framework, you will see no performance gains as the library will still run against the same .NET Framework.

If you ported your whole app itself to .NET Core (which will be even easier when 3.0 is out), you would definitely see the performance gains, as your library will then run on .NET Core.

As for porting - it is usually easiest to just create an empty library and manually copy the existing classes to the new library and then install all required NuGet packages.

Comment: Assuming the OP knew all this, this answer does in no way answer the question asked.

Comment: From the question it does not seem OP knew the difference - even using the name  NET Core Standard vs NET Core - those two things are not comparable - one is API interface and one is platform. Also the answer responds to the migration question as well. I am not sure what is missing :-)

Comment: This does not answer the question. "This means if you upgrade an existing .NET Framework 4.6.2 library to .NET Standard, you are only getting portability of the library". Yes, that is what this question is looking for.

Comment: @ThomasBoby Sorry, but I must disagree with you in this regard. The question asks if porting the library to .NET Core vs. .NET Core Standard, of these two, the second option fundamentally does not exist, so I figured it is necessary to first clear up this misunderstanding. This was necessary to show the performance gains are actually decided by the runtime the library will be used in - because for Core library the perf gain is automatic, but for Standard library is conditional.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Well, let us change the question to be about migrating to .NET Core and .NET Standard then, which is a very valuable question with no current answer. My understanding is that there can be performance issues with using a .NET standard build of a class library (as you can't use upstream performance improvements from APIs in netstandard2.1 or netcoreapp3.0 for example)

Comment: This answer is very relevant to the question even though it may not directly give the user the answer. Far too many times people fail to realize that there is more to answering a question than just the answer itself. 

Context is very important as it supports the answer and can lead to the OP finding said answer on their own. Which in my book is far more powerful than just giving the answer.

@MartinZikmund, thanks for the context, it helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Martin's answer, to migrate your existing .NET Framework application to .NET Core, you can first start with [portablility analyzer tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer). This tool is a Visual Studio extension and gives a detailed report on how flexible your application is.

Migration your existing project to .NET Core is a journey and it can take some time depending on the nature of your solution. This tool is quite useful in determining the state of your project. 
If you are only targeting .NET framework 4.6.2, the migration should be relatively straightforward. Here is what you could do:

1. Create new .NET SDK Style project [image]
2. Edit the `csproj` file of new project and change the target framework to net462.

`<PropertyGroup> <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework> </PropertyGroup>`

3. Move your files from old project to new project.
4. Delete your old project and update the references
5. Repeat step for all the class libraries

I would suggest to start with a class library with minimum dependencies, test the changes and move to more complex ones once you have converted all the simple ones.

Comment: Thanks, But If we target to net462 still it will be pointing to .NET framework only even we migrate to .NET Core.
So, My main motive is to move .NET Framework to Core is performance gain, But If we still pointing to net462 in a core application will there be any gain or loss in performance?

Comment: To move to .NET core I would suggest to start with analyzer tool first and see the compatibility of your application. The rest of the steps can still remain same. If your application is 100% compatible you can choose target as `netcoreapp2.0`   (or now `netcoreapp2.1`). Else, convert the project to new style but keep the target as `net62`, convert all incompatible code to `.net core` and then change the target framework to `.netcore`.